# verifyBeforeUpdateEmail doesn't send verification link

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication

**Issue:**
I'm facing an problem where updating a user's email doesn't trigger the expected email verification link. I've tested this with different email providers, and the verification link isn't being sent.

**Expected Behavior:**
When updating a user's email using Firebase Authentication, I expect Firebase to send a verification link to the new email address. This link is crucial for users to confirm their ownership of the updated email.

```
API call code: 
export const updateUserInfo = async (firstName, email, credentials) => {
  const currentUser = auth.currentUser;
  let emailUpdated = false;

  try {
    await reauthenticateWithCredential(currentUser, credentials);

    if (currentUser.email !== email) {
      await verifyBeforeUpdateEmail(currentUser, email);
      emailUpdated = true;
    }

    await updateProfile(currentUser, {
      displayName: firstName,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }

  const userDocRef = doc(db, 'Users', currentUser.uid);

  try {
    await updateDoc(userDocRef, { email: email, displayName: firstName });
  } catch (dbError) {
    console.error('Error updating user data:', dbError.message);
    // Handle database error
    throw dbError;
  }

  return emailUpdated ? 'Please confirm email' : 'User info updated';
};
```